# Mapping elements in my form to names from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some javascript code that pulls values from a form by its `name` value(for example by getting `document.myForm.txtBox.value`), and does some calculations, and outputs the values in different textboxes, again by using the textboxes names (ex. `document.myForm.result1.val = result`). I have another form with the same textboxes and inputs, however the elements are named differently and the document is structured differently. Is there a way to map values from my inputs to the inputs of this other form, submit it, and grab the results?

For example create a mapping like:

```
{
     document.myForm.txtBox.value:myTxtboxVal,
     document.myForm.txtBox2.value:myTxtbox2Val,
     ...
}
```

and then pass this data to the other form and get the results?

Comment: Do you have any html to provide to see how different they are? Can't you loop through the input of your form and map it to the other ones?

Comment: You can add arbitrary attributes to your elements. Like this `<input data-other="myTxtboxVal" ... >` You can grab that and use it as index: `otherForm[dataOther].value` (Also, because this seems something people do for some reason but I don't get why: don't *output* stuff in a textbox. Just use a `<p>` or the like and set its `.innerText`)

Comment: *I have another form* Q:  Is this "another form" on the same html page as the first one.

Comment: No the other form is completely separate

Comment: Also, this sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Performing some other form's calculation shouldn't require the 2nd form's involvement in any way.

Comment: I guess I could loop through the input of my form, but I guess I'm confused as to how I could use that to run the calculations in the javascript file since it grabs the element values by name